# Menu Bar in Top of Desktop not visible for some Applications like Rhythmbox

Tags: unity, rhythmbox, menu

When starting and activating **Rhythmbox** there is no menubar available since installing Ubuntu 13.04 using an existing user profile of a home-partition from previous versions of Ubuntu.

When I create a new user and log in as this new user, I get the menu bar.

But when I log in back to my "old" user profile, the menu bar is gone.

I already tried `unity --reset`, which does not solve the problem.

Can anyone point me how to reset my user profile in a way to display the menu bar?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found that the menu bar depends on which session you use not on the new and old user. If you use gnome classic you ain't going to find ordinary menu bar but by clicking on RB icon (name) on the the desktop top bar you will find everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

To turn on or off use of the top bar to display application menus:

1. Install `gnome-tweak-tool`
2. Select the tab labelled "Top Bar"
3. Toggle "Show Application Menu"

An alternative is to make rhythmbox show the settings gear icon.  To do this, run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides '{"Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu":<0>}'
```

then restart rhythmbox.

Source: https://extensions.gnome.org/review/1239