# Rhythmbox menu bar is not visible

Tags: 13.10, rhythmbox, menu-bar

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 Rhythmbox (3.0.1) menu bar is not visible in my laptop and desktop (Office).

Comment: Create a new account - does the RB toolbar appear for this new user?  How did you install RB 3.0.1? Was RB working before you upgraded to 3.0.1? Please add any replies as edits to your question.  Thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom  I tried with a new account, but still things are the same. Before upgradation it worked well and I installed RB using following command:  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jacob/media
 sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox. Thank you.

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you open a bug report?

Comment: even i have this issue.

Comment: Try this link, its also the same problem
https://askubuntu.com/questions/292755/menu-bar-in-top-of-desktop-not-visible-for-some-appliations-like-rhythmbox/506565#506565

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn on or off use of the top bar to display application menus:

1. Install gnome-tweak-tool
2. Select the tab labeled "Top Bar"
3. Toggle "Show Application Menu".

An alternative is to make rhythmbox show the settings gear icon.  To do this run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides '{"Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu":<0>}'
```

then restart rhythmbox

Source: https://extensions.gnome.org/review/1239

Comment: Please do not repost answers to multiple questions.  If a question is solved by the same answer and is the same problem, then please mark those questions as duplicates instead.

Comment: In 19.10, my gnome-tweak Top Bar section has no "Show Application Menu". This might not be my problem though, because Dropbox shows up fine in my top bar, but Rhythmbox does not.